# Objective-C EXC_BAD_ACCESS with assign object property

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access

The `delegate.deviceToken` expression below sometimes throws a bad pointer dereference, apparently out of `objc_retain()`.

**MyWebServices.m:**

```
@implementation MyWebServices

+ (void)initializeWithCompletionBlock:(void (^) (id data))completionBlock withErrorBlock:(void (^)(NSError* error))errorBlock {
    AppDelegate* delegate = (AppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    if (delegate.deviceToken == nil) { // MyWebServices.m:29
       ...
    }

    ...

}
```

The **AppDelegate** declares `deviceToken` like so:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString* deviceToken; // #NotMyCode
```

Quoth the **crash report**:

```
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000f434c4388
Triggered by Thread:  0

0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000180a940b0 objc_retain + 16 (objc-object.h:341)
1   MyApp                               0x0000000100054f98 +[MyWebServices initializeWithCompletionBlock:withErrorBlock:] + 200 (MyWebServices.m:29)
2   MyApp                               0x000000010003b97c -[AppDelegate initializeWebServices] + 224 (AppDelegate.m:380)
3   MyApp                               0x00000001000b123c __47-[AFNetworkReachabilityManager startMonitoring]_block_invoke + 132 (AFNetworkReachabilityManager.m:199)
```

The call to `-[AppDelegate initializeWebServices]` can come out of the `AFNetworkReachabilityManager` code, as it does in this case, or out of my `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`. My `deviceToken` is indeed *not* initialized in `AppDelegate`, and so with it's `assign` semantics it seems clear that I am trying to dereference garbage. But how does the nil check cause a call to `objc_retain`?

Clearly it's worth trying to initialize `deviceToken` to `nil`, or update its memory management semantics. Also noteworthy in the code are a few booleans, the intent of which seems to be the protection of calls to `initializeWebServices`, and which may be managed poorly.

But I have no idea how to reproduce this bug.

Comment: referring to deviceToken within a block will indeed cause a retain to be attempted, so that the value of deviceToken will valid during the scope of your block.

Comment: Your property should be `copy` or `strong`, not `assign`

Comment: Also, the nil check wont help here, since your pointer is not nil. It's a pointer to a deallocated object.

Comment: Also, you can make your BOOLs _volatile_ if you are reading them from multiple threads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The property is mis-declared; it should use the `strong` or `copy` attribute instead of `assign`:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* deviceToken;
```

Using `assign` means the object is not being retained correctly, hence the exception.

Comment: Properties of type `NSString` should almost always be declared with `copy` semantics (not a problem here, though).

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe Why is that? If it's to ensure the object isn't changed *behind your back* (so to speak) then why is that limited to `NSString`?

Comment: It's not limited to NSString (but to value types conforming to `NSCopying`). Usually it's done for `NSString` and most collection types. These types are class clusters where the immutable subclasses implement `-copy` as a no-op. So it's cheap when not necessary and expensive when actually needed.

Comment: I would have thought it should be the case for all objects with a mutable subclass in order to ensure the data remains *sane*.  I never do this myself, but I can see the point, especially in classes provided in libraries/frameworks.  I will amend my answer; thanks.

Comment: "All objects with a mutable subclass" is difficult to define. `NSDate` is a value class without mutable subclasses. On the other hand, nobody keeps you from implementing one. In the end it boils down to best practices (NSString and collections).